# How to build this array right and get its unique values (GAS)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to get unique values from an array, but apparently this array is built incorrectly and doesn't allow me to achieve the a.m. goal.

I have set below several examples of attempt and all of them give the result on the image below the code:

```
var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A7:s3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 48)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var productList = new Array();
  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(productList.indexOf(data[i][0])==-1) {
      //mgrA.push(vA[i][3]);
      productList.push(data[i][0],data[i][2], data[i][18]); //These are the columns which, together, can help me create an identifier.
    }
  }
  var productObj=[];//This was an object. 
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
      if(productList[i]==data[j][0]){
        if(productObj.hasOwnProperty(productList[i])) {
          productObj[productList[i]]+=Utilities.formatString('%s%s%s',data[j][0],data[j][2],data[j][18]);
        }else{
          productObj[productList[i]]=Utilities.formatString('%s%s%s',data[j][0],data[j][2],data[j][18]);
        }                                               
      } 
    }
  }
  //Attempt1
  const distinct = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }

  const distinctProd = productList.filter(distinct);
  Logger.log("Test1: " + distinctProd);
  //Attempt2
  const distinctProd2 = [...new Set(productObj)];
  Logger.log("Teste2: " + distinctProd2);
  //Attempt3
  var unique = Array.from(new Set(productObj));
  Logger.log("Test3: " + unique);
```

This is the result I'm getting:
[image]

This is the expected result:
21.1Desenvolvimento,21.1Aprovação,21.1Ativo

Comment: Please explain what you mean? `I am trying to get unique values from an array`

Comment: Hi. I just corrected it, so we can see the image I uploaded with the results. It shows 21.1Desenvolvimento repeatedly, it doesn't include a comma delimiter..., @Cooper

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have just added the expected the result at the bottom of the question, @Cooper.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to remove duplicates from `productList`?

Comment: Well...yes. The productList gives me one row only, so I thought I had to remove the duplicates from productObj, instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You shared the expected result, but not the input data. Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you're working, or at least a sample of the original data you're working with?

Comment: Hi! Here's an example of the data I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N6znnKQIIDvTK1A4PLgQbLxAdTXTQ53HncaeeoQ77zE/edit?usp=sharing , @Iamblichus! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work:

```
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(list.indexOf(data[i][0])==-1) {
```

The above is looking for data[i][0]s you cannot use this approach if you're going to follow it by pushing more than data[i][0]s in the the list because then it will always be == to a -1

If you wish to collect these three items data[i][0],data[i][2], data[i][18] then do so in a second list

```
      list.push(data[i][0],data[i][2], data[i][18]); //These are the columns which, together, can help me create an identifier.
    }
  }
```